# How to fix error "'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'field_name'"

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to extract some the **student_ID** and **student_name** from a model which has a manytomanyfield relations. unfortunately, i don't know how to go about that. The method i tried resulted into the attribute error i got.

models.py

```
class add_courses(models.Model):
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Manager_Name = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    syllabus = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    classroom = models.CharField(choices=choices, default='in person', max_length=12, blank=True)
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=14, default='', blank=True)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Course_Name

class add_students_by_manager(models.Model):
    manager_ID = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name

    @staticmethod
    def matching_loging_stu(userID):
        try:
            return add_students_by_manager.objects.get(student_ID=userID)
        except:
            return False
```

views.py

```
def assignment_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        get_course_name = request.POST.get('get_course_name')
        add_courses_get = add_courses.objects.get(Course_Name=get_course_name)
        stu_course_all_stu = add_courses.objects.filter(Course_Name=add_courses_get)
        print(stu_course_all_stu)

        for m in stu_course_all_stu:
            print(m.student.student_ID)
            print(m.student.student_name)

        context = {"stu_course_all_stu":stu_course_all_stu, "get_course_name":get_course_name}
        return render(request, 'assignment_page.html', context3)
```

Comment: `add_courses.student` is a many to many field. So `m.student` is a **related manager** not an instance of `add_students_by_manager`. If you want all related instances then you should iterate over `m.student.all()`. (**Note**: use `PascalCase` to name classes also model names should be **singular**, also class names should ideally **not have verbs**)

Comment: Thank you sir...

Comment: I am trying to get the result in the template but it is not working. check the updated question please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944873/how-to-fix-the-issue-add-students-by-manager-object-is-not-iterable

Comment: Please help with the updated question