# How to fix display data in manytomanyfield in my template in Django website

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to display some data in my templates by passing it as context but i get  `'add_students_by_manager' object is not iterable` I noticed that the problem actually has to do with outputting the result on the template. how can i fix this please.

models.py

```
class add_courses(models.Model):
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Course_Name

class add_students_by_manager(models.Model):
    manager_ID = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

views.py

```
def assignment_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        get_course_name = request.POST.get('get_course_name')
        stu_course_all_stu = add_courses.objects.filter(Course_Name=add_courses_get)

        for all_stu_details in stu_course_all_stu:
            for stu_details in all_stu_details.student.all():
                print(stu_details.student_ID)
                # THIS PRINTS OUT ALL THE student_id
        context3 = {"stu_course_all_stu": stu_course_all_stu, "stu_details": stu_details}
        return render(request, 'assignment_page.html', context3)
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

assignment_page.html

```
        {% for m in stu_details %}

        <div class="card mb-3 ml-5" style="max-width: 840px;">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="/media/uploads/student_user.png" class="rounded profile-pic mt-2 ml-5 mb-2" alt="user" height="120" width="140">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Student ID : {{m.student_ID}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Student Name : {{m.student_name}}</h5>
                <form action="{% url 'stu_id_details' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="get_id_stu_details" value="{{m.student_ID}}" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">See Student Details</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
because you are not rendering the queryset to template , you are only printing it in your views using a for loop.You can do it in this way


views.py

ls = []
for all_stu_details in stu_course_all_stu:
    ls.append(all_stu_details)
context3 = {"stu_course_all_stu": stu_course_all_stu, "stu_details": ls}
return render(request, 'assignment_page.html', context3)


html


{% for m in stu_details.student.all %}
<h5 class="card-title">Student ID : {{m.student_ID}}</h5>
<h5 class="card-title">Student Name : {{m.student_name}}</h5>
```